# How to by pass network using WebProxy?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, webproxy

If I want to bypass a Network like 192.168.1.0/24 using webProxy is there any way?

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();

proxy.ByPassList = ???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set it up in Internet Explorer and then use

<strike>WebProxy proxy = (WebProxy) WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();</strike> Deprecated.

```
var iproxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
var url = new Uri("http://www.example.com");
var wp = new WebProxy();
wp.Credentials = iproxy.Credentials;
wp.Address = iproxy.GetProxy(url);
```

or you could try to add `"192.\.168\.1\.*"` to proxy.BypassList with something like

```
List<string> bypasslist = new List<string>(proxy.BypassList);
bypasslist.Add("192.\.168\.1\.*");
proxy.BypassList = bypasslist.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks I was trying to fetch the Intenet Explorer Proxy Settings through registry (headbang) ... :-)

Comment: +1 but

Warning 1 'System.Net.WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy()' is obsolete: 'This method has been deprecated. Please use the proxy selected for you by default.

is there any alternative that you know?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know it was deprecated. I've had success with WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()

Comment: `192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` ? `[a-z]+\.labcrm2015rsg\.com$` ? is valid `https://www.nuget.org/api/*` ?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot alter the bypass list after the proxy creation. Use the following constructor overloads:

```
Uri address = ...
proxy = new WebProxy(address, **true**);
```

**true** means "bypass on local", and should be enough for you needs if you are using a 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

or if you want to add a custom list:

```
Uri address = ...
proxy = new WebProxy(address, true, new string[] {"192.168.1.1","intranet",...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
WebProxy lb_proxy = new WebProxy("PROXY_IP", PROXY_PORT)
{
     BypassProxyOnLocal = true,
     BypassList = new string[] { "192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2",...}
};
httpRequest.Proxy = lb_proxy;
```